# How to edit a generated html table

Tags: javascript, html, dom, html-table

I have a function that would get a json object and turn it into a table. My problem is how can I edit the contents of the table. For example I wanted link inserted in the table to have href properties and the image description to be an image like that

here is my function that generates a table on click

```
$.get("output-tv.php",{tv_type:tv_type,screen_size:screen_size,connectivity:connectivity,features:features},function(response){
            var i = 0;
            var table = document.getElementById("table")
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            $("#table tr").remove(); 

                for(i=0; response.result.length-1 >= i ; i++ ){
                    var table = document.getElementById("table");
                    {
                        var row = table.insertRow(0);
                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);
                        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);
                        cell1.innerHTML = response.result[i].product_code;
                        cell2.innerHTML = response.result[i].tv_name;
                        cell3.innerHTML = response.result[i].size;
                        cell4.innerHTML = response.result[i].tv_type;
                        cell5.innerHTML = response.result[i].link;
                        cell6.innerHTML = response.result[i].image;
                    }


                }   
            }, "json" );
```

Comment: It would be much easier if you use jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/C9N9E/

Try this fiddle ,instead of using JavaScript for adding rows to table ,utilize jquery completely.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        debugger;
       // $("#myTable tr").remove();
        $(jsonObj.items).each(function () {
            var rowString = "<tr>";
            rowString += "<td>" + this.index + "</td>";
            rowString += "<td>" + this.name + "</td>";
            rowString += "<td><a href=" + this.Link + " >"+this.name+"</a></td>";
            rowString += "<td><img src='" + this.logo + "'  height='30' width='60'/></td>";
            rowString += "</tr>";
            $('#myTable').append(rowString);
        });

    });
```